Add shortcut on Chrome home page (Android phone)
How do I add a shortcut to the Chrome Home page? I accidentally deleted one and cannot figure out how to restore it.
"Add to Home screen" adds a shortcut to the andoid home screen, not the Chrome home page. I see this question over and over on different sites about adding a shortcut to Chrome and every single answer adds to the Android home screen.
I have tried finding a way to paste a shortcut onto the Chrome home page.
I have clicked on the three dots and the "Add to Home screen." It added a shortcut onto the Android home screen, not Chrome.
I have long-pressed the icon to the left of the URL I'm trying to add to the Chrome home page.
I have selected (long-pressed) the URL but it only lets me edit or copy the URL.
I'm considering sacrificing a chicken under a full moon.

Adding shortcuts directly to the Chrome home page isn't a feature that Chrome currently supports. The Chrome home page typically displays your most visited websites and Google search bar.

well if that link is so important, you can change home page to that link, so when you click on home icon, you will be redirected to that link. to do that go to chrome settings, click homepage, choose 2nd option and paste your link.
